# Regression results with all negative coefficients

Tags: least-squares

The coefficients of my regression output including the c constant are all negative. What could be the problem, or how do I interpret the result.

Answer (score 2):

Why should it mean you have a problem?

What is clear is that your variables are negatively related. If you increment your `x` it will mean a decrease in your `y`. If `x` is decreased, `y` will increment.

The constant `c` comes from this formula:

```
c = mean(y) - slope*mean(x)
```

The negative constant does not mean much.

Answer (score 0):

If all your coefficients are negative isn't a problem!

You should interpret the result in this way: If you change the variable X_{1} to X_{1} + 1 and keep all the other variables the same, then the response Y will be decrease by beta_{1} points.

In the same way you could interpret the other coefficients.

Hope this help you.